# Как использовать свою музыку?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть исходники замечательного проекта https://github.com/Nasso/urmusic
Там визуализируется музыка с soundcloud или та которую загрузил клиент.
Я бы хотел что бы по дефолту использовалась моя музыка из директории и она соответственно визуализировалась сразу после захода на сайт, но я так и не смог это сделать.

Comment: _моя музыка из директории_ - из какой? локальной? или сервера? для локальной - невозможно

Comment: @Grundy , естественно с сервера

Answer (score 1):

ВВ данном примере человек сам должен загрузить музыку в браузер. После краткого изучения кода это делается через вот такой код

```
    <div style="display: none;">
        <a id="downloader"></a>
        <input type="file" id="fileChooser" multiple />

        <audio id="audioElement" loop></audio>
    </div>
```

Соответственно в вашем случае его надо получить с сервера. Для этого надо написать (добавить к существующему) веб серверу функциона для передачи музыки на клиент.

99% работая с Java на сервере первое, что пришло в голову это Spring MCV. Быстро загугли нашел вот такое решение:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786602/allowing-audio-files-in-spring-mvc-3-0

Соответсвенно получается, что указывая определенную папку на сервере сервер будет вычитывать и передавать на клиент.